Ionic (Ver 7.8) - How to change height and centre text in ion-input?
The question is can you customise an ion-input by changing the height and centering the text.
I've created a simple input element with a counter. What I would like to do is reduce the height of the input field and centre the text. Showing on dark background just for legibility while developing.

What I actually want is for it to look like this:

I'm not bothered about the location of the label. I can add a transform etc for that.
What I can't do is make the input area 50 px high and centre the text. The only things which seem to have an impact are adding --padding-bottom to centre the text, but that's a nasty hack. It centers the text by making the overall height greater - so give me no actual control over the height.
I've tried to just move the input text up a bit:
input, .native-input {
  transform: translateY(17px);
}

But this doesn't do anything. Note that I was able to move the label text to the centre with this (and I'm not proud of this code) :
   .monkey-input {
      @extend .text-large; // input text settings
      letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
      // transform: translateY(-7px);// *
      .monkey-input-label { // Don't apply above to label
        @extend .text-medium;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        transform: translateY(-7px);
      }

      /** Label div */
      > input, .native-input {
        transform: translateY(-7px);
      }

But can't figure out how to add the same effect for the input text. NB: Applying transform: translateY(-7px);//* just moves the entire input box up, not just the text.
What I'd like to do is set the height and align the text without needing to resort to hardcoded magic numbers of pixels etc! Code like that isn't going to work in a responsive design.
